# Click event on yAxis Gantt Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am new in javascript, so building this Gantt Highcharts is a complete new world for me.
I could create successfully the Gantt Chart, but now we need to add a click event on the y axis Labels (the category names Cat1, Cat2, Cat3 bellow).

We tried adding under the Y-axis/labels/events a funcion for 'click' but nothing happens.

Do you have a clue on what might it be, please?

Comment: ```
yAxis: {
    labels: {
      events: {
        click: function () {
          // Your click event logic here`your text`
          alert('Y-axis label clicked!');
        }
      }
    }
```
```

Comment: It would be helpful to potential responders, and therefore to you, if you'd edit your question to include your markup and code, and a fuller statement of the issue.   Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The axis label click event is not directly available from the API. However, you can use the customEvents module to achieve this. Simply attach the following module to your code or obtain it from npm.

```
<script src="https://blacklabel.github.io/custom_events/js/customEvents.js"></script>
```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/az742n5e/